# CakePHP 3 - Load posts from users a user is following

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Trying to load all posts from users a user is following in a "Cakey" way.

Three tables:

**users** (id, username, password)

**posts** (id, text, user_id, created)

**follows** (id, user_id, following_id)

I think my relationships are set up correctly, so I can load a users followers and the people following them:

Users Table

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Following', [
        'className' => 'Users',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'following_id',
        'joinTable' => 'follows'
    ]);

    $this->belongsToMany('Followers', [
        'className' => 'Users',
        'foreignKey' => 'following_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinTable' => 'follows'
    ]);
```

Follows Table

```
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Posts Table

```
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

Now struggling to select all the posts from the users a single user follows. Think I need to use the `matching()` method documented here: [Filtering by Associated Data Via Matching And Joins](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data-via-matching-and-joins) but don't seem to be getting it right.

Trying something along these lines:

```
$user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

$posts = $this->Posts->find()->matching('Users.Following', function ($q)  use ($user_id)  {
      return $q->where(['Users.id' => $user_id]);
})->all();
```

> **UPDATE:**

I think I have my relationships set up correctly, this find will return the user, along with all the users they are following:

```
  $users = $this->Posts->Users->get(1, [
      'contain' => ['Following']
  ]);
```

Comment: Put your find() query here

Comment: Added to the question. I think I'm going along the right lines...

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: Please, add to your question the three table relationships separately. You add one but you did not tell which table they belongs

Comment: I've added my relationship details

Answer (score 0):

You missed to inherit `$user_id` to the `matching anonymous function`.

```
$user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

$posts = $this->Posts->find()
    ->matching('Users.Following', function ($q) use ($user_id) {
          return $q->where(['Users.id' => $user_id]);
    })
    ->all();
```

> **Closures** may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
>   variables must be passed to the use language construct. From PHP 7.1,
>   these variables must not include [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php), `$this`, or variables
>   with the same name as a parameter.

See also [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

> **UPDATE:**

Add to Users Table

```
$this->hasMany('Posts', [
   'className' => 'Posts',
   'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
]);
```

Controller

```
$users = $this->Posts->Users->get(1, [
    'contain' => ['Following.Posts']
]);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's one thing that was missing, but I'm still not getting the posts from only the users that that user follows, I'm getting all the posts

Comment: I'd say there's even more problems, `Users` is the wrong alias for the condition, and the matching should maybe be done against `Followers` instead of `Following`, AFAICT it would otherwise retrieve the posts of the users that are followers of user `$user_id`, instead of the posts of the users where user `$user_id` is a follower.

Comment: I've added to my question an example query that returns the users the user is following, so I think the relationship is correct1

Comment: @RayannNayran thanks for your help. That approach was always going to work, but not quite what I'm after. That returns an array of user entities, which in turn contains an array of that user's posts. Ideally, I want just an array of post entities which comprises of the posts from the users the user is following.

Comment: I'm sure I need to do something with the matching function https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data-via-matching-and-joins

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in a comment *'Ideally, I want just an array of post entities which comprises of the posts from the users the user is following.'*
A simple find query with proper join conditions should do the work :

```
 $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

 $this->loadModel("Posts");
 $posts = $this->Posts->find('all')
            ->select()
            ->where(["users.id" => $user_id])
            ->join([
                'follows' => [
                    'table' => 'Follows',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => 'follows.following_id = Posts.user_id'
                ],
                'users' => [
                    'table' => 'Users',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => 'users.id = follows.user_id'
                ]
            ]);

$posts->toArray();
```

**Note:** I haven't used any `belongsToMany`,`belongsTo` relationships you defined in models

I hope this will solve your problem.